# How to append 4 digit number to the next string read from file

Tags: java, string, file, append, file-handling

I have one file to read which is like this

mytxt.txt

```
1234 http://www.abc.com

8754 http://www.xyz.com
```

I tried with this

```
try {  
        // make a 'file' object   
        File file = new File("e:/mytxt.txt");  
        //  Get data from this file using a file reader.   
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);  
        // To store the contents read via File Reader  
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);                                                   
        // Read br and store a line in 'data', print data  
        String data;  

        while((data = br.readLine()) != null)   
        {  
            //data = br.readLine( );                                       
            System.out.println(data);  
        }                                  
    } catch(IOException e) {  
        System.out.println("bad !");  
 }
```

I used this but the actual question is I want to read one this two charachter one by one and then appens the digit to the link which I'll read as string.
Can anyone tell me how I am suppose to do that..?
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you give an example output that you require?

Comment: The output that I want is something like www.abc.com/1234 using which I can navigate to that site with the help of selenium webdriver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse the line you are reading, search for the first white space (I'm assuming you have only one space separating your digit and your url) something like this:

```
try {  
    // make a 'file' object   
    File file = new File("e:/mytxt.txt");  
    //  Get data from this file using a file reader.   
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);  
    // To store the contents read via File Reader  
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    // Read br and store a line in 'data', print data  
    String data;  

    while((data = br.readLine()) != null)   
    {  
        int posWhite = data.indexOf(' ');
        String digit = data.substring(0, posWhite);
        String url = data.substring(posWhite + 1);
        System.out.println(url + "/" + digit);  
    }                                  
} catch(IOException e) {  
    System.out.println("bad !");  
}
```

Comment: String.split would be a cleaner alternative to manually searching through the string.

Comment: Is the first thing I thought as well, but in some weird cases I've found URLs with spaces inside them (Firefox now allows you to type such URLs, although it internally "escapes" then) so finding just the first space would be safer

Comment: `data.split(" ", 2)` will handle that case.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
   while((data = br.readLine()) != null)   
    {                                      
        String[] data=br.readLine().split();
        if(data!=null&&data.length==2)
          {
           System.out.println(data[1]+"/"+data[0]);
          }else
          {
            System.out.println("bad string!"); 
           }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the while((data = br.readLine()) != null), make the code like this:

```
String tmpData[] = data.split(" ");
System.out.println(tmpData[1] + "/" + tmpData[0]);
```

Comment: Thank you, I got upto this but the real question is how to append the first temData[1] to other temData[0] and then print it together. as I have to navigate to browser with the resuletant output

Comment: Got the answer...String test =new StringBuffer(tmpData[1]).append(tmpData[0]).toString();